# How to spell vis-à-vis out loud

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

Vis-à-vis is a word on the spelling bee list, but I'm not sure how to say the accented "a" when spelling it out loud.  Can you please help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80 As a general note, you can simply enter any letter or punctuation mark of your liking into a Wikipedia search box and you'll get right to the dedicated article.

Answer (score 11):

"À" is called "[a-grave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80)", named after the accent it is sporting – a "grave accent".

If you ever come across a different letter with the same accent, it'll be called "*letter*-grave", e.g. e-grave (È).

Other accented letters will be named similarly. The cedilla (¸) [e.g. in *façade*], grave (`) , acute (´) [e.g. in *résumé*], circumflex (ˆ) [e.g. in *fête*] and diaeresis (¨) [e.g. in *naïve*] are among the most common accent marks that speakers of English are likely to encounter. (The umlaut is identical in appearance to the diaeresis, but modifies the sound of the vowel it is attached to differently to the diaeresis.)

Comment: A complication in some cases is that when the source language is not one that calls the diacritic by the names most often used in English then we might use the English name or we might use the name from that source language. In this case the source language also calls the character *grave* (and indeed is the source language of *grave* itself) so in this case it's "a-grave" either way.

Comment: @Kareen: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223123/

Comment: @Erik Kowal: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223123/

Answer (score 7):

> How to spell vis-à-vis out loud:

**Vis-à-vis**: V ... I ... S ... dash ... ***[a-grave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80)*** ... dash ... v ... i ... s: ***[vis-à-vis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vis-%C3%A0-vis)***:

> **Origin**
>
> mid 18th century: French, literally 'face to face', from Old French
>   vis 'face'.

In the word "a-grave" the first *a* is pronounced like the a in D*a*ve, while the second *a* is pronounced like the *a* in su*a*ve (**[gräv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio)**).

Comment: If I wanted to spell out *gräv*, how would I do that?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr `mit zwei punkte` my German teacher would say.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I hope DigitalTraumas german teacher would say `mit zwei Punkten` instead of `Punkte`. :P Anyway, since the `ä` in `gräv` has nothing to do with the german `ä`, I'd say you spell it out like `a-diaresis` or `a-trema` (but definitely not `a-umlaut`).

Comment: @waka Most likely ;-)  Its been quite a long time...

Comment: @Good A.M.: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223123/

Comment: @ScotM: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223123/