# How to spell vis-á-vis out loud

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

Thank you very much to the 4 people who quickly responded a few days ago as to how to spell vis-á-vis out loud for an upcoming spelling bee.  I apologize that the moderator did not think it was on-point and closed my question (he probably will close this one, too!)  I had done a lot of on-line research and still could not find the answer.  My son actually won the all-school spelling bee yesterday, so your help was quite meaningful.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Jen. This is a comment posed as a question. It will be removed. With a small amount of reputation, you could thank the people individually in comments under their answers, even on closed questions.

Comment: This isn't a question. It should ideally have been a comment on the earlier question. However, congratulations to your son!

Comment: Congratulations, Jen! Did he have to spell vis-a-vis? This is a feel good moment. Thanks for your thoughtful heads up @medica.

Comment: It helps if you get the written version right: vis-à-vis. That's an a-grave, not an a-acute (which doesn't exist in French).

Comment: Be a good sport; up vote this post so Jen can comment on the on her original post.